# Is all WSO2 API Manager's configuration saved in the database?

Tags: docker, configuration, wso2, wso2-api-manager, docker-build

Say one implements a WSO2 API Manager Docker instance connecting to a separate database (like MySql) which is not dockerized. Say some API configuration is made within the API Manager (like referencing a Swagger file in a GitHub).

Say someone rebuilds the WSO2 API Manager Docker image (to modify CSS files for example), will the past configuration still be available from the separate database? Or does one have to reconfigure everything in the new Docker instance?

To put it in another way, if one needs to reconfigure everything, is there an easy way to do it? Something automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the configurations are stored in database. (Some are stored in internal registry, but registry saves data in database at the end)

API artifacts (synapse files) are saved in the file system [1]. You can use API Manager's [API import/export tool](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment) to migrate API artifacts (and all other related files such as swagger, images, sequences etc.) between one server to another.

[1] `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/`